# CultureInfo "weird" responses to large names (strings)

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling

I am a pentester and while fuzzing an API I found a "weird" response that seems to stem from a default .Net class CultureInfo. Now I am not a huge expert on .Net, I am not even a developer, so sorry if this is a noob question.

CultureInfo takes a name with a locale like en-US or nl-NL and can return locale specific information from the system.

When fuzzing this locale (so the nl-NL part) I got two different responses for locale larger than 152. I fuzzed only the last part, the country part, so the requests to CultureInfo look like this: nl-AAAAAA (and more AAAA's).

One response was an error "Culture is not supported" with some extra information. This I got for most requests with more than 152 A's.

The weird thing is that for certain values I got a "normal" default response back that assumes that nl-ANYTHING means you want the results for nl-NL and no error was generated. This was for example (amount of A's):
190, 198, 255, 266 and 1900
I do not see a direct connection to why these amounts of A's generate no error while the others do.

Now this error most likely (if I go through the source) stem from GetCultureInfoHelper() that is called in GetCultureInfo() from the CultureInfo() class. This is called with an lcid of 0 and would create a new CultureInfo class using the name parameter. The name parameter would then be nl-(A*190). Normally that breaks and returns a null and the error, but with certain amounts of A's it does not break there and returns the correct values.

The actual question is: why is it doing this? Why not always error out, or always return a default value?

More information:
This all runs in a .Net container on a linux server (as far as I know) running a x64 Amazon Linux (not sure if it is Amazon Linux or an Ubuntu/Debian).

Source of the .Net that is most likely important:

```
    public static CultureInfo GetCultureInfo(string name)
{
  if (name == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (name));
  CultureInfo cultureInfoHelper = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoHelper(0, name, (string) null);
  if (cultureInfoHelper == null)
    throw new CultureNotFoundException(nameof (name), name, SR.Argument_CultureNotSupported);
  return cultureInfoHelper;
}
```

This part is part of the GetCultureInfoHelper method and is the only part that actually returns a Null (as far as I can tell):

```
      CultureInfo cultureInfo2;
  try
  {
    switch (lcid)
    {
      case -1:
        cultureInfo2 = new CultureInfo(name, altName);
        break;
      case 0:
        cultureInfo2 = new CultureInfo(name, false);
        break;
      default:
        cultureInfo2 = new CultureInfo(lcid, false);
        break;
    }
  }
  catch (ArgumentException ex)
  {
    return (CultureInfo) null;
  }
```

**Edit:**
More info on the class:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: FYI the work of verifying names that are not on the list of supported names is done in nativeInitCultureData in the CLR, but offhand I do not recall where the source code for that is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't find anything on nativeInitCultureData except for other remarks on SO. Where would I start to search for the source of this?

Comment: Ok found the CultureData references and seeing how the flow goes. Still don't really know why it errors sometimes but not always. I think it might be some weird way it builds a new cache when locale is not found in cache. But I don't know...

Comment: @Wealot: If you stuff the whole thing in a simple `for` loop, are you able to reproduce these results? If so, please replace your code example with that, since it makes for a more self-contained code sample.  If not, your problem is probably in the code we can't see.  Obviously I'm in a different environment than you, but I tried this both locally and via https://dotnetfiddle.net/23290b and the only matching cultures I found were nl-AA and nl-AAAA .

Comment: @Brian: thanks for looking at it. When I have time (IF I have time.....) I am going to rebuild the environment. As it is some sort of .Net container in some Unix system. So might be to do with how the container communicates with the system.